# invalid syntax after multiple if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
knowledge = input().lower()

if knowledge in list1:
    m = float(input())

if knowledge in list2:
    g = float(input())

if knowledge in list3:
    Fz = float(input())

if knowledge in list4:
    W = float(input()

if knowledge in list5:
    F = float(input()

if knowledge in list6:
    Δx = float(input()
```

List 1 to 6 are all defined in another part of the code, for example: list1 = "m", "mass", "kg"

From the if statement of list 4 (including the if statement from list 4 and further ones), I get an invalid syntax, which points to the ":" at the end of the if statement of list 4.

When removing the if statement of list 4, it will point to the ":" of list 5, and so onward.

What is happening here, and how do I fix it? Is it cause of my big amount of if statements?

Comment: Check your parentheses (and consider using variable names people can actually type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have unclosed `float()` parenthesis:

```
knowledge = input().lower()

if knowledge in list1:
    m = float(input())

if knowledge in list2:
    g = float(input())

if knowledge in list3:
    Fz = float(input())

if knowledge in list4:
    W = float(input())

if knowledge in list5:
    F = float(input())

if knowledge in list6:
    delta_x = float(input())
```